# How to separate file name and file path in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a path like "C:\Users\Rick\html.txt". So how can I separate the file path and filename? My main aim is to extract the file path and obtain "C:\Users\Rick" for a text editor app. I'm receiving the path as a QString from QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(). So I want to use that path as the window title and next path if the user tries to open a file

````cpp
if(!checkTextField()){
       QMessageBox::StandardButton reply = QMessageBox::question(this,this->appName,this->document_modified);
       if(reply == QMessageBox::Yes){
           QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Save the File",QDir::homePath(),this->textFilter);
           QFile file(filename);
           if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text))
               return;
           QTextStream out(&file);
           QString text = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
           out << text;
           file.flush();
           file.close();
       }
    }```
````

Answer (score 3):

You should look in to [QFileInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html)

```
QFileInfo info("c:/my/path/to/dir/file.txt");
info1.absoluteFilePath();   // returns "c:/my/path/to/dir/file.txt"
info1.dir();                // returns "c:/my/path/to/dir"
info1.filename();           // returns "file.txt"
```